# examine picture through sliding window

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have [this image (too large to include)](http://i45.tinypic.com/339hd7t.jpg) (`2351x997`) and I'm trying to detect the horizontal lines, first I have to apply a window as

```
M=T(1:d,1:l);
```

`T` is my image, `d` is width (4 pixels) and `l` is the length (`l=0,2*2351`) of my area of interest. Then in this window I have to count black pixels (`n`), the mean value (`m`) and standard deviation (`σ`).

Afterwards if `n/(lxd) >0.6` and `σ<1,2` I assume I detect a line.

The applied window will slide through image in step of `l/4`

Comment: so [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) ?

Comment: Are you stuck at the implementation or the algorithm? Did you read [this](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/linedet.htm)?

Comment: I've post my code so far,  I have done the mask and i think i can get black pixels by find or getpixel, however how can I apply the condition in order to characterize a line?

Answer (score 0):

You can try follow this example,

[SCW Example](http://lebgeeks.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=7786)

Comment: Thanks all of you, what I've done is T=imread('test.tif'); [m,n]=size(T);
l=round(0.2*n);
d=4;

for r=1:m-d
    for k=1:round(l/4):n-l
mask=T(r:d+r-1,k:k+l-1);
level=graythresh(mask);
mns=mean(mean(mask));
if level<0.6
    level
end
    end
end